# Почему не отрабатывает WM_GETFONT?

Tags: delphi, winapi, шрифты, delphi-xe2

Для формы делаю:

```
hFont := SendMessage(Self.Handle, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
```

Но возвращает 0. Т.е. как будто у формы установлен системный шрифт.
Почему так?

А если сделать, например, так:

```
hFont := SendMessage(CheckBox1.Handle, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
```

То возвращает корректный дескриптор.

Тоже самое, например, для TPanel - hFont = 0.
А для кнопки hFont - корректное значение.

Answer (score 2):

WM_GETFONT - это не совсем системное сообщение, его надо обработать самому.
Диалоги хранят у себя в недрах объекта окна переменную, которую и связывают с сообщениями WM_GETFONT/WM_SETFONT:

> When the dialog box has the DS_SETFONT or DS_SHELLFONT style, the
>   system sends a WM_SETFONT message to the dialog box procedure and to
>   each control as it creates the control. The dialog box procedure is
>   responsible for saving the font handle passed with the WM_SETFONT
>   message and selecting the handle into the display device context
>   whenever it writes text to the window. Predefined controls do this by
>   default.

(см. подробности в [Dialog Box Fonts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644994(v=vs.85).aspx#fonts))

это сделано для централизованного управления шрифтом, чтобы диалог мог пройтись по всем своим дочерним элементам и выставить этот единый шрифт.

Форма и панель - это кастомные элементы Delphi (тоже окна, но не диалоги), поэтому не реагируют на эти сообщения. Delphi вообще не использует классические диалоги, поэтому некоторые их возможности она реализует по своему (свои велосипеды).

Answer (score 0):

[**WM_GETFONT message**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632624(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Retrieves the font with which **the control** is currently drawing its text.

Есть мнение, что TForm и TPanel не являются Control, с точки зрения WinAPI и WM_GETFONT/WM_SETFONT к ним не применимо. Т.е. стандартная оконная функция просто не обрабатывает это сообщение.